# Webstorm Karma Test Runner Not Working with Yeoman angular-fullstack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, webstorm

I created a web application using the Yeoman [Angular-Fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator. Everything runs correctly from the command line. I can use grunt to start the service and run tests.

I want to run the Karma unit tests inside the Webstorm user interface. I right clicked on `karma.conf.js` and had Webstorm create a Karma run configuration for me. When I try to run that configuration, it spins for a few seconds then fails.

The Karma Server window in Webstorm contains this:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijServer.js --karmaPackageDir=/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/node_modules/karma --configFile=/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/karma.conf.js
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/client/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/client/app/app.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/client/components/**/*.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/client/components/**/*.jade" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/client/app/**/*.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/client/app/**/*.jade" does not match any file.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 29_J57vgWL6mWwyV13tv with id 98142631
```

Which all looks correct to me. The Test Run window contains this:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js --karmaPackageDir=/Users/williammcneill/Documents/Work/LearnNode/gecko/node_modules/karma --serverPort=8080 --urlRoot=/
/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js:54
      throw e;
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I can't figure out what is timing out. If I open http://localhost:8080 I see a webpage that looks like this.

[image: Local host on 8080 when debugging the Angular application]

Which also looks correct to me.

I haven't actually written any code. I'm taking all the defaults that Yeoman and Webstorm give me. I think I have all the relevant Webstorm plugins (AngularJs, Karma).

Does anyone have insight into what might be happening or how I could debug it?

*Webstorm 10.0.4, Yeoman 1.4.8, Karma 0.13.9, Node 4.1.0, OS X 10.10.5*

Answer (score 0):

The `port` value in `karma.conf.js` is set to 8080, even though the server runs on 9000. Change this value to 9000 and everything works.

Not sure exactly how the grunt configuration makes it all work, or why it's set up this way, but that's the workaround.